# one entity attributes gets persisted to other entity attributes

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I want to perform a jpa related program that have functionlity like when I enter values for attributes in parent entity those need to updated in other table with same attributes is there a way to do these ..im using eclipse link 4.0.2
I tried inheritance and relations but relations create another table I don't want that and in inheritance we need to enter values separately

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.